# Name 'Cinemachine' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cinemachine

I'm a beginner of Unity and C#. I'm trying to manipulate the cinemachine camera using a script, but the VScode throws an error saying `The type or namespace name 'Cinemachine' could not be found`. So I tried removing the cinemachine from the package manager and reinstalled the cinemachine, but I still get the same error. I searched the same issue on StackOverflow and got [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63895695/namespace-name-cinemachine-could-not-be-found), but since I don't make an assembly file, it does not solve my current issue. So could anyone tell me what to try next to solve the issue which I currently have?

Comment: It'd help if we could see the script in question.

Comment: Did you install the according [Cinemachine package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.cinemachine@2.8/manual/index.html) into your project via the [Package Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui.html)?

Answer (score 1):

[image]Go to Windows >> Package Manager >> on Packages (Select Unit Registry) >> Search "Cinemachine" >> Install & Import

Answer (score -1):

Does VS say "Miscellaneous Files" at the top left of the window?
if the answer is - yes -  so its a common VS issue that won't allow it to "see" any of the Unity classes. If so [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/visual-studio-problem.507850/#post-3317346) could help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).